# Grunt test for UMD

Tags: javascript, node.js, requirejs, jasmine, gruntjs

I'm trying to figure out the best approach to testing a Javascript module definition using a UMD factory, similar to this: https://github.com/umdjs/umd/blob/master/returnExportsGlobal.js

I don't want to test the module itself, I want to test that the module is 'exported/created' correctly in the various environments:

1. If CommonJS (node), is the module exported correctly?
2. If AMD, is it defined correctly?
3. If browser (without requirejs), is the correct global created?

I would like to run these tests using grunt and jasmine. I can use grunt-contrib-jasmine to test for points 2 and 3, but not for point 1.

I guess I can use a concoction of grunt-contrib-jasmine and grunt-jasmine-node to test for correct module definitions (specific implementation i'd still need to figure out), but it feels very messy.

At a high level, does anyone know of any existing methods to achieving this without using multiple grunt plugins?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the end, i decided to go with the hybrid tasks, using grunt-contrib-jasmine for browser global and browser AMD tests, and jasmine_node for CommonJS testing. I only have one spec 
file which supports all 3 module type tests.

Here's my grunt config:

```
grunt.initConfig({
  pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
  jasmine: {
    browserGlobal: {
      src: ['src/Foo.js'],
      options: {
        specs: 'spec/**/*.spec.js'
      }
    },
    browserAMD: {
      src: ['src/Foo.js'],
      options: {
        specs: 'spec/**/*.spec.js',
        template: require('grunt-template-jasmine-requirejs')
      }
    }
  },
  jasmine_node: {
    specNameMatcher: 'spec',
    projectRoot: 'spec/'
  }
});
```

My jasmine spec files now support UMD:

```
(function (root, factory) {
  if (typeof module === 'object' && module.exports) {
    // Node/CommonJS
    factory(
      require('modulename')
    );
  } else if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
    // AMD
    define([
      'modulename'
    ], factory);
  } else {
    // Browser globals
    factory(root.ModuleName);
  }
}(this, function factory(ModuleName) {

 // Tests here
}));
```

And here's the UMD factory i'm using for my module:

```
(function (root, factory) {
  if (typeof module === 'object' && module.exports) {
    // Node/CommonJS
    module.exports = factory();
  } else if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
    // AMD. Register as an anonymous module.
    define(factory);
  } else {
    // Browser globals
    root.ModuleName = factory();
  }
}(this, function factory() {


  // public API
  return {
    foo: 'bar'
  };
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [uRequire](http://urequire.org) and save your self from all the UMD boilerplate in all your modules, while using [declarative features](http://urequire.org/#how-about-declarative-either-per-module-or-whole-bundle-:).

You simply write plain AMD or plain CommonJS modules (or a mix of two) and convert to UMD (or an rjs optimized `combined.js` that runs as-is on **nodejs**, **Web/AMD** & **Web/Script**) with a simple [build step and config](http://urequire.org/#a-spartan-module-builder-config), either in CLI or in [grunt](https://github.com/aearly/grunt-urequire).

The UMD produced is based on well known templates like https://github.com/umdjs/umd/blob/master/templates/returnExportsGlobal.js, with various tweaks, one of them being that you can [declaratively export to `window`/`global`](https://github.com/aearly/grunt-urequire).

You can then convert you plain AMD or commonJS specs to UMD and/or 'combined.js' and hit both in  a browser or grunt-mocha. See [uBerscore](https://github.com/anodynos/uBerscore) for many trivial and more advanced examples.